# Unable to use vimeo-upload in angular 8 project

Tags: angular, module, constructor, vimeo, vimeo-api

I am trying to use [vimeo-upload](https://github.com/websemantics/vimeo-upload) in one of my angular project ot directly upload video files from browser. I have tried the way it is described in the official docs [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vimeo-upload)

I have also tried including the script in index.html file and also included it in angular.json script section.

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: vimeo_upload__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.VimeoUpload is not a constructor
    at VimeoUploadService.uploadToVimeo (vimeo-upload.service.ts:13)
    at AssignmentComponent.onSelect (assignment.component.ts:25)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (AssignmentComponent.html:20)
    at handleEvent (core.js:43993)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:45632)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:45247)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:29804)
    at core.js:31837
```

I am using the library in following way:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { VimeoUpload } from 'vimeo-upload';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class VimeoUploadService {

  constructor() { }


  public uploadToVimeo(file: File) {
    const uploader = new VimeoUpload({
      file,
      token: '7e1779c21af53374e5ae1d6be5d6e465',
    });
    uploader.upload();
  }

}
```

Can anyone suggest how to use this library in the angular code.

Comment: did you try to declare `private vimeo: VimeoUpload` in the cnstructor and then using it?

Comment: If I try to do that the whole service breaks. This is expected, since the VimeoUpload is not a constructor it can neither be instantiated in constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue resolved.

I opened the JS file for [vimeo-upload](https://github.com/websemantics/vimeo-upload) an found that it exported the whole function by setting it to module.exports.

Therefore, while importing it one will have to import is as single namespace rather than the object notation I was trying in my original post.

Hence, the following works fine:

```
import * as VimeoUpload from 'vimeo-upload';
```

or

```
import VimeoUpload from 'vimeo-upload';
```

More abut module importing here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Hope it helps someone.